# Can't embed binary of embedded project in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have a main project, `Project One`, which is a macOS Swift app. I've added a subproject, `Project Two`, which is a Command Line Tool. I'd like the built command line tool to be embedded as a binary into the bundle of `Project One.app` where it will be called by `Process()`.

However, I am stuck getting the built binary to embed into the main app.

[image]

I set things up like so:

- created the first main project as usual
- created a new project in Xcode 9.3 (a Command Line Tool, in Swift)
- in the Finder, dragged the `Project Two.xcodeproj` file into the Xcode sidebar, where you see it in the screencast
- compiled Project Two — it then appeared in Project Two's `Products` folder

I *can* drag it into "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" but even after doing that, I can't drag it into Embedded Binaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to go to the "Build Phases" tab, and then create a new "Copy Files" build phase. You'll then be able to drag the tool into the newly created build phase. Make sure to also add the tool's target to the Target Dependencies build phase, or you'll create a race condition into your build process that will randomly make builds fail.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. However what then is the Embedded Binaries for? Just for compiled frameworks? And why can't we embed tools this way instead of the 'copy files' method?

Comment: @jeff-h I don't remember "Embedded Binaries" being there, TBH, so it may be a relatively recent addition (although it's also possible that I just didn't notice it before). I played around with it a bit, and it appears to be "syntactic sugar" of sorts. With certain file types, adding something to Embedded Binaries automatically sets up the Target Dependencies and Copy Files build phases for you. But it only works for types it knows how to handle, and command-line tools aren't one of them. Probably because iOS doesn't have command-line tools, and no one loves us macOS devs these days.